Azure Data Factory Web Activity doesn't return any respond while using the API to start the azure VM
Hi I've created new azure vm which will be used as self hosted runtime in Datafactory. I've also given my datafactory as Contributor role in that newly created azure vm.
I want to automate my vm start and deallocate process from ADF itself. For that I've used the web activity in datafactory with System-assigned managed identity for authentication.
for the azure REST API POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/start?api-version=2024-07-01.

Also I've also enabled the idendity for a vm access from azure data factory.

Problem
Once the web activity runs with that rest api to start the vm from its deallocate state, the activity keeps on looping with no response until the activity gets time out, but in background my vm starts from its deallocate status to running status whereas I don't get any response from the web activity which is so weird.
But while turning off the vm, I've no issue in even using the same API, it is able to deallocate the vm from its running state and also the API will respond with some output.
This weird issue is biting me for a while.
can you please help me?

As per the Start API and Deallocate API documentations,

This APIs won't return any output related to VM in its Response.

After starting the VM, the web activity will succeed within 1 minute. You can see the same below which I have created same as yours.
Start:

VM started:

Deallocate:

VM stopped:

If you want to automate this process, first check the status of the VM and then do the process of start/stop the VM. First call the Instance view REST API using a web activity. Then check the status in an if activity.
In the True and False activities of if activity, give your web activities to start and Deallocate VM.
You can go through this blog by @David Alzamendi to learn more about this approach.

Hi @Rakesh, the problem for me is that web activity continuously run unlike 1 min like you are mentioning. So while starting VM this web activity continues running,... but in background vm will start

set a timeout in the web activity settings and try by using giving 1 or 2 value in the retry as mentioned in the mentioned blog.
